# Let Resharper force this keyword on fields

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, this

Does anyone know if it is possible to have resharper force the use of the this keyword when it can be used? For fields and such...

Resharper is capable of showing where it can be removed, but our coding standard tells us to use the this keyword.

Comment: I'd argue that `this` is redundant (with constructors as a possible exception) because you shouldn't give method arguments or local variables the same names as fields.

Comment: I'm not talking about the same names... private fields start with an _, parameters don't (in our guidlines). It is much easier to spot distinct methods, properties and fields from local variables and parameters, even with differences in casing...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In ReSharper Options, under *Code Editing -> C# -> Code Style* there is an option for *Use "this." qualifier for* that you can set for fields, properties, events, and methods.

Comment: That's what I thought too... This setting removes the squigglies. I'm looking for a way to get a squiggly line when one of my co-worker forgets to use this.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  I don't think there's an included code inspection for that (just the included "redundant this" inspection).

Comment: StyleCop will yell at you when you leave out the "this." keyword. Seems a workaround would be to use both tools.

Comment: Try finding this in R# 9. :/ ... wait Code Editing -> C# -> Code Style

Comment: Yep, it's there now in Resharper 9!

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the StyleCop for Resharper plugin (part of the [StyleCop project](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/)).

You can then set the "default" severity for StyleCop to Error (or just this particular rule) and it will appear in the R# "files with errors" area inside Visual Studio.