# Can I make using `this` mandatory in my code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to make qualifying members of the current instance with `this.` mandatory? I prefer the clarity.

Details:

In C#, if you have instance members (fields, properties, methods, etc.), normally you can refer to them both with and without `this`, e.g.:

```
class Foo
{
    private int bar;

    Foo()
    {
        // These two lines are both valid, and both do exactly the same thing
        bar = 42;
        this.bar = 42;
    }
}
```

In my coding style, I don't want `this` to optional, I want the first line above to cause at least a warning. Obviously this is just for my own purposes, I'm not trying to mark the resulting assembly in some way that requires people *using* it to also do this, this is purely a personal style thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use programs such as [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (using [the setting described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4087407/157247)) and [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) (using [this rule](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1101.html)).

They allow you to define your own coding styles which cause validation warning in your code with suggestions on who to resolve them.

Here is a question on free alternatives to resharper.

[What are some alternatives to resharper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834439/what-are-some-alternatives-to-resharper)

Comment: When stylecop is installed it should make this rule mandatory

Comment: ReSharper has the option to force "this." qualifier. See [Let Resharper force this keyword on fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087361/let-resharper-force-this-keyword-on-fields)

Comment: Both of them have this, cool. (Updated the answer.) Would prefer it if VS.Net itself had something, but so far it's not seeming like it.

Comment: Do you also enforce "this" on properties and methods? If not: Why? If so: Doesn't it bother you cluttering your code with "this" all over the place?

Answer (score 1):

StyleCop seems to have this rule switched on by default.